# Save strings in android in order to remember radio button choice, age in editText - sample code

Tags: java, android, string, save

So basically what I want to do is to save strings for selected choices and some entered text in edit texts (to remember age that kind of things that don't change easily/fast) so when the user restarts the application he doesn't need to enter all that information again.

But I've been looking all over the internet about saving strings in shared preferences or internal memory and I can't understand lots of things and I can't get it to work.

So my question is can someone please provide me sample code for 1 radio group or 1 `editText` (it's enough) how to remember the selected choice in string or the entered value so the next time when the app is started that string is called the choice/text is set automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from a previous answer of mine, but it will work for you.

```
private void savePreferences(){
    // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("editText1", editText1.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("editText2", editText2.getText().toString());

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
}

private void restorePreferences() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    editText1.setText(settings.getString("editText1", ""));
    editText2.setText(settings.getString("editText2", ""));
}
```

Call `savePreferences()` in `onPause()` if you want to save all changes by default or in an OnClickListener if it suits you better. You should call `restorePreferences()` in a method like `onCreate()` to load these values as the app starts.

Comment: dude I saw your post previously but it didn't worked coz I put first line: private void savePreferences(){ - inside OnClickListener, and I got errors, turned out I don't need the starting and the ending line. Thanks a lot! :) by the way I'm pretty new to android.. :P

Comment: I meant use `savePreferences();` in the OnClickListener not whole the method... But I'm glad you found a solution. Please click the check mark to accept this answer. Good luck!